# Available computer-assisted translation (CAT) software for Ubuntu

Tags: 13.10, software-recommendation, translation

Does anyone know any good (if any) computer-assisted translation (CAT) software for Ubuntu 13.10?

Answer (score 0):

The list is quite extensive. These are those [listed by Wikipaedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-assisted_translation#Some_notable_CAT_tools) with an open source licence:

- [GlobalSight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GlobalSight)
- [Gtranslator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gtranslator)
- [Lokalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lokalize)
- [OmegaT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OmegaT)
- [Open Language Tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Language_Tools)
- [Poedit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poedit)
- [Pootle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pootle)
- [Virtaal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtaal)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Omegat, the default ubuntu CAT application

OmegaT's main features are

- ability to run on any operating system supporting Java
- use of any valid TMX file as translation reference
- flexible sentence segmenting (using an SRX-like method)
- searches in the project and the reference translation memories
- searches in any directory including OmegaT-readable files
- fuzzy matching
- smart handling of projects including complex directory hierarchies
- support for glossaries (terminology checks)
- easy to understand documentation and tutorial
- localization in a number of languages. OmegaT supports OpenDocument
  files, Microsoft Office files (using OpenOffice.org as a conversion
  filter, or by conversion to HTML), OpenOffice.org or StarOffice
  files, as well as (X)HTML, Java localization files, PO files, OpenXML
  , DocBook or plain text files.

To install

```
sudo apt-get install omegat
```

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/natty/omegat/